# Custom Form on Shopify

Tags: forms, shopify

I'm new to JS and Liquid.

We have a custom form where we ask for details based on the membership selection.

On submit the details are sent to Klaviyo and from there they receive an email.

But now I have a few issues which I am not able to figure out.

1. Validate all the fields that have not been filled.
2. Show the Success message after clicking the Sign-Up.

Also, We have asked for ID proof to be uploaded. Is there a way to send the uploaded file via email or is it we need to send it to the server.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you need to check the Kalaviyo forms for it, and create a new custom form according to your requirements and append the form to the website. or need to use any 3rd party APP like privy, POWR

Comment: Take a look for APP here : https://apps.shopify.com/search?q=forms